# Shell script not installing python3-pip correctly

Tags: command-line, scripts, python3

I've set up a script to install a bunch of stuff for a project I'm working on as well as an easy way for me to install python modules that I use. 
When I run this, it does accurately show if python3+ is installed it also installs python3 if it's not there.

It downloads portaudio configures and builds it. It works up to when I try and install python modules and then it fails. The error I get is

```
/usr/binpython3: No module named pip
```

If I manually sudo apt-get install python3-pip it does work and if I re-run the script it does
finish installing all of the below python modules. Can anyone tell me why it's not installing python3-pip correctly? Or is it that it's not setting the path right? Is there a better way for me to do this?

```
if [ $(id -u) = 0 ]; then
    echo "Do not run as root, yet. Try again."
    exit 1
fi

req=`python3 -c 'import sys; print("%i" % (sys.hexversion<0x03000000))'`
if [ $req -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'python version is >= 3'
    echo 'Installing dependices'
    sudo apt-get install python3-pip libexpat1-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.5-dev python-pip-whl python3-dev python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.5-dev build-essential git python3-dev ffmpeg libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libportmidi-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev zlib1g-dev swig libpulse-dev python3-audio libasound-dev
    sudo apt-get update
else 
    echo "python version is < 3"
    echo "Installing Python3+ and dependencies" 
    sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip libexpat1-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.5-dev python-pip-whl python3-dev python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.5-dev build-essential git python3-dev ffmpeg libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libportmidi-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev zlib1g-dev swig libpulse-dev python3-audio libasound-dev
    sudo apt-get update
    echo "Python 3 is now installed." 
fi 
read -p "Install remaining dependencies?(y/n)" ok
wget - http://www.portaudio.com/archives/pa_stable_v190600_20161030.tgz
tar -xvzf pa_stable_v190600_20161030.tgz
cd portaudio
echo n | ./configure && make
echo n | sudo make install
sudo apt-get update
echo n | sudo -H python3 -m pip install Cython==0.23 pyttsx3 chatterbot PyAudio PocketSphinx SpeechRecognition kivy==1.9.1
sudo -H python3 -m pip install bleach boto boto3 botocore bz2file cffi click colorama command-not-found cryptography cssselect decorator docutils fire flashtext Flask future gensim google-api-core google-api-python-client google-auth google-cloud-core google-cloud-storage google-resumable-media googleapis-common-protos html5lib httplib2 idna imbalanced-learn jedi Jinja2 jupyter jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyter-core kappa Keras  luminoth lxml nltk notebook numpy pandas pendulum Pillow pyasn1 pycrypto Pygments pygobject PyICU pymongo PyNaCl PyOpenGL PyQt5 PySDL2 pySFML python-dateutil python-twitter pytz PyYAML pyzmq qtconsole regex requestium requests rsa scikit-learn scipy selenium setuptools sip six SQLAlchemy ssh-import-id style tensorflow tensorflow-gpu tensorflow-tensorboard Theano tornado tqdm  urllib3 wheel xkit xlwt
if ! [ $ok = "y" -o $ok = "Y" ]; then exit 1

fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your apt-get command fails without you noticing. It is not clear what version of Ubuntu you are working on, but at least in 16.04 the package "python3-audio" does not seem to exist, making the command fail.

Try putting the correct name of the package (probably "python3-pyaudio") in your script.

In general it looks like a system like [ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) instead of a shell script would be more appropriate for what you are doing here.

Comment: Yep that was it. Commands were failing at a package that didn't exist thank you! Also thank you for that ansible link I'll look into it!